# PHP Xpath JS how to get content from site with JS?

Tags: javascript, php, xpath

I want to get innertext of site that I use xpath, for some reason in the Chrome Developer (F12) I see the text, but in view-source I didn't. I assume it's loaded with javascript or something else.
I want the get the price of the product
Here is my code:

```
$link = "https://joybuy.com/651140653.html";
$html = file_get_contents($link);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$prices = $xpath->query('//strong[@id="sku-price"]');
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the data comes as JSON Response, data can be obtained from this URL, [check this out](https://ipromo.joybuy.com/api/promoinfo/getPriceInfo.html?json=%7B"skuId":651140653,"site":1,"channel":2,"curList":["USD","EUR","RUB","GBP","CAD","CHF","AUD","PLN","MXN","BRL"]%7D&callback=getMainPrice&_=1536522233226) here the  `skuId` changes for each product, if you change the `skuId` you will get the prices for other products as well

Comment: how you find it?

Comment: from the inspect element you can see network tag, open it and reload the page you can see different types of data which are loaded to the site